# C++ Variable declaration of type class does not name a type?

Tags: c++, class, declaration

Im having a problem involving declaring variables that are of a type class.

Example code

```
class Party{
     public:

     string partyName;
     Leader leader;
     Candidate candiate;
     nationalcompaignManager nationalManager;
     natioanlfinancialManager financialManager;
     compaignMananger newcompaignMananger; 
};

class Leader: public Person {

    public:
     int popularity;
     int totalcountryVotes;
}
```

As seen in this code snipit, there are several variables declared of a type of a class, in this example ive demonstrated how a class Leader does exist for a variable leader;

Error code example(as its the same for all)

```
 error: ‘Leader’ does not name a type
      Leader leader;
```

There are classes for each variable but for sake of simplicity I'll work with Leader. Leader is clearly defined  as a class in the program scope, yet variables of its type are not? Im unsure as to why this error is occuring

Comment: You have to define `Leader` before (above) you use it in the struct (EDIT: class).

Comment: I dont have any structs @Mestkon

Comment: `class`es and `struct`s are conceptually the same thing.

Comment: You might also want to fix the spelling of campaign :)

Comment: Both `class` and `struct` define _classes_.

Comment: @Mestkon And candidate! Also some weird capitalisation going on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just declare `Leader` above `Party` to make it "visible" to `Party` class.

```
class Leader
{
};

class Party
{
  Leader leader;
};
```

Comment: Note that whilst this is indeed a declaration it is also a definition of `Leader`; it may be good, for completeness, to mention that it is only the former that is necessary in this context, and that we could likewise (barring the discussion of best and worst practices) make use of a (non-defining) [forward declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Forward_declaration) to `Leader` without necessarily defining it prior to `Party`.

Comment: @dfri -  Not true.    A declaration that is not a definition is insufficient if an instance of `Leader` is a member of `Party`.    What you say is only true if `Party` contains a reference (e.g. of type `Leader &`) or a pointer (e.g. of type `Leader *`)

Comment: @Peter Ah as a (non-reference/non-pointer) member `Leader` is used in a context where it is required to be complete?

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a language of sequential nature which means that it starts compiling your code from top to bottom. So before you declare a class variable, you should first define that class before the declaration otherwise there is no existence (till it is defined) of the class and thus, resulting in an error.

```
class Leader
{
};   //The class Leader is now defined.
class Party
{
Leader leader;
};
```

In simple words, you cannot use something that hasn't been created.